# Need help in C# UWP GamePad class running in Xbox one

Tags: uwp

I am using the class Gamepad to be able to get the reading of the xbox controller but when running on the xbox one and I press the B button it exit out of the program. And I can not find a way to stop it. If any one knows how to stop from exiting the program because I had other function for the B button.

Comment: Looks to me it is a system behavior. Can you provide more details about the steps to reproduce this issue? Is it on your main page and what is the function that you write for your B button? How did you handle the back navigation from your code, like this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/gamepad-and-remote-interactions#gamepad-and-remote-control) mentioned?

Comment: Thank for responding but I found the way to stop the B button from going out of the program and only work the way that I was planing to do.

Comment: Glad to know that, do you mind to share an answer to show what you have done?

Comment: In my mainPage() I added 'SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested +=
        SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested;' and the the method 'private void SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested(
object sender,
BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Handled)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }' giving it true I am telling the system that I am taking care of it. If I place false the system will exit me out of the program in the Xbox One.